# AWS RDS MySQL performance

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am running MySQL 8 on AWS RDS, I have an InnoDB type table with 260,000 rows inside, no extraordinary data size.

My development server features 1GB RAM, 1vCPU, and my AWS RDS server is t3.small.

SELECT Count operations take too long (average 33 seconds) and my data tables in my Laravel project time out, what could be the problem?

```
select count('special_cargo_id') from special_cargos
```

33seconds

Answer (score 4):

Is special_cargo_id your PK, what is it's type, and does it fit into innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Run:

```
select count(1) from special_cargos;
```

a few times. Does it run quickly after the first time? If it does, then the reason it slows down sometimes is because you are memory starved and other data pushes your PK on that table out of the innodb_buffer_pool. If it is always slow, the PK most likely never fits into the buffer pool.

Comment: When I run this code, it gives results in 22 seconds when I make a query, where can I look at the size of the innodb buffer pool?

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';`

Comment: Resulted in 2147483648, total table size 1,95GB

Comment: single queries completion time is 0.05 second, the problem happens in multiple queries, can it be related to indexing settings?

Comment: That makes no sense on a server with 1GB of RAM. It should probably be about 500MB in a server with 1GB of RAM. Different queries depend on different indexes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to debug performance of your Database, RDS has a great built in tool for that.

With [RDS Performance Insights](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/performance-insights/) you should be able to identify where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I select the database and enter the modified page but there is no setting where I can enable performance insight